# lightning:select Formatting not like in Lightning UI

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Anyone know how to get the `<lightning:select>` options to be formatted like they are supposed to be?

Simple example below placed in the right side gf the Account lightning page

**Lightning App**

```
<aura:component description="myExampleComponent" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"
                access="global">

    <lightning:select name="sel" label="try Me" >
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
    </lightning:select>
</aura:component>
```

Result when in LEX and showing options:

[image]

When in the account and creating an opportunity using default SF LEX UI the StageName options look like this:

[image]

Is there any way to get the options for the `<lightning:select>` to appear like they do when using salesforce provided components? I would think that the lightning select options was supposed to be styled like the lightning select not just the select input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would expect components in the `lightning` namespace to match the LEX design in the future, even though we can't say when/if this will happen.

In the meantime, the guys at Appiphony have made a great job creating components that match the [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) look & feel.

Have a look at the Strike components, in this case the [Strike Select](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeSelect) one, which is exactly what you want. These are free and open source. In the future, when `lightning:select` will be matching the LEX UI, you'll just have to replace the strike component by the standard one.

[image]

Comment: Ha, forgot all about this question. Been beta testing the strike components since they came out and find them amazing. The fact that I submitted issue number 1 was cool in a geeky way to lol

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not the answer as such, but wanted to share what I did. I recently spent some time on this, I *think* you'd have to implement your own [Pickist from SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/picklist/#flavor-base-picklist-open-item-selected). If you inspect the DOM on the Opportunity form, you'll see that the rendered list on the Opportunity is a `div` rather than `select` that the `lightning:select` renders.

I used this half-way solution to style the Select as I found implementing a Picklist component to be troublesome being pretty new to the whole Lightning framework and for my needs, I wasn't that bothered (I pinched this CSS from Process Builder 'new' which does use `select` rather than `div`)

```
.THIS select {
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 35px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(216, 221, 230);
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 97.5% 50%;
    background-size: .875rem .875rem, 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: The select is not the main issue, although it disappoints, it is the options that I am having the main issue with.....Thanks for this though, it does style the select much better than default.

Comment: Yes agreed its annoying. I guess these components will come as standard over time. I did have some success implementing the Picklist but found that the drop down wasn't behaving around other components - for example getting chopped off at the bottom of the parent div. I just gave up. Be interested to see what others come up with.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using all of the available SLDS and plus javascript and available Aura Javascript to emulate the behaviour of a select list.

I took the example from the SLDS documentation and added `aura:id` tags to it. [SLDS base picklist open](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/picklist/#flavor-base-picklist-open)

**component**:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="currentCheckedPicklistIds" type="String[]" />
    <div aura:id="dropdown" class="slds-picklist slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click">
      <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">Categories</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right slds-picklist__input"> 
            <input aura:id="selectedOption" type="search" id="text-input-01" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input" placeholder="Select an Option" aria-owns="option-list-01" role="combobox" aria-activedescendant="" aria-expanded="true" readonly="" />
            <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-button slds-input__icon slds-text-color--default" iconName="utility:down"  onclick="{!c.openDropdown}" alternativeText="Open or close dropdown."/>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--left slds-dropdown--length-5" role="listbox">
        <ul aura:id="checklist" id="option-list-01" class="slds-dropdown__list" role="presentation">
          <li aura:id="option1" role="presentation" onclick="{!c.checkOption1}">
            <span class="slds-lookup__item-action slds-lookup__item-action--label" role="option" tabindex="0" id="listbox-option-2279">
                <lightning:icon aura:id="optionIcon1" class="slds-hide slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" iconName="utility:check" size="xx-small" />
                <div aura:id="padding1" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" />
                <span aura:id="content1" class="slds-truncate">Option A</span>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li aura:id="option2" role="presentation" onclick="{!c.checkOption2}">
            <span class="slds-lookup__item-action slds-lookup__item-action--label" role="option" tabindex="-1" id="listbox-option-2280">
                <lightning:icon aura:id="optionIcon2" class="slds-hide slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" iconName="utility:check" size="xx-small" />
                <!-- fake the padding because nothing lines up... -->
                <div aura:id="padding2" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" />
                <span aura:id="content2" class="slds-truncate">Option B</span>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li aura:id="option3" role="presentation" onclick="{!c.checkOption3}">
            <span class="slds-lookup__item-action slds-lookup__item-action--label" role="option" tabindex="-1" id="listbox-option-2281">
                <lightning:icon aura:id="optionIcon3" class="slds-hide slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" iconName="utility:check" size="xx-small" />
                <!-- fake the padding because nothing lines up... -->
                <div aura:id="padding3" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" />
                <span aura:id="content3" class="slds-truncate">Option C</span>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li aura:id="option4" role="presentation" onclick="{!c.checkOption4}">
            <span class="slds-lookup__item-action slds-lookup__item-action--label" role="option" tabindex="-1" id="listbox-option-2282">
                <lightning:icon aura:id="optionIcon4" class="slds-hide slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" iconName="utility:check" size="xx-small" />
                <!-- fake the padding because nothing lines up... -->
                <div aura:id="padding4" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" />
                <span aura:id="content4" class="slds-truncate">Option D</span>
             </span>
           </li>
          <li aura:id="option5" role="presentation" onclick="{!c.checkOption5}">
            <span class="slds-lookup__item-action slds-lookup__item-action--label" role="option" tabindex="-1" id="listbox-option-2283">
                <lightning:icon aura:id="optionIcon5" class="slds-hide slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" iconName="utility:check" size="xx-small" />
                <!-- fake the padding because nothing lines up... -->
                <div aura:id="padding5" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" />
                <span aura:id="content5" class="slds-truncate">Option E</span>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li aura:id="option6" role="presentation" onclick="{!c.checkOption6}">
            <span class="slds-lookup__item-action slds-lookup__item-action--label" role="option" tabindex="-1" id="listbox-option-2284">
                <lightning:icon aura:id="optionIcon6" class="slds-hide slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" iconName="utility:check" size="xx-small" />
                <!-- fake the padding because nothing lines up... -->
                <div aura:id="padding6" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small slds-shrink-none" /> 
                <span aura:id="content6" class="slds-truncate" title="Option FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ">Option FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</span>
            </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

**controller**:

```
({
    openDropdown: function(component, event, helper) {
        var dropdown = component.find("dropdown");
        if($A.util.hasClass(dropdown, "slds-is-open")) {
            $A.util.removeClass(dropdown, "slds-is-open");
        } else {
            $A.util.addClass(dropdown, "slds-is-open");
        }      
    },

    checkOption1: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.performCheckActions(component, "option1", "optionIcon1", "padding1", "content1"); 
    },

    checkOption2: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.performCheckActions(component, "option2", "optionIcon2", "padding2", "content2");
    },

    checkOption3: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.performCheckActions(component, "option3", "optionIcon3", "padding3", "content3");
    },

    checkOption4: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.performCheckActions(component, "option4", "optionIcon4", "padding4", "content4");
    }, 

    checkOption5: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.performCheckActions(component, "option5", "optionIcon5", "padding5", "content5");
    },

    checkOption6: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.performCheckActions(component, "option6", "optionIcon6", "padding6", "content6");
    }
})
```

**helper**:

```
({
    performCheckActions : function(component, optionId, optionIconId, paddingId, contentId) {
        this.resetPreviousCheckedOption(component);
        this.storeAsCurrentlyCheckedValue(component, optionId, optionIconId, paddingId);
        this.checkOption(component, optionId);
        this.showOptionIcon(component, optionIconId, paddingId);
        this.setInputBar(component, contentId); 
    },

    showOptionIcon : function(component, iconName, paddingName) {
        if( !iconName || !paddingName ) {
            return;
        }
        var option = component.find(iconName);
        var padding = component.find(paddingName);
        if($A.util.hasClass(option, "slds-hide")) {
            $A.util.removeClass(option, "slds-hide");
            //hide the padding
            var padding = component.find(paddingName);
            $A.util.addClass(padding, "slds-hide")
        } else {
            $A.util.addClass(option, "slds-hide");
            $A.util.removeClass(padding, "slds-hide");
        }       
    },

    checkOption : function(component, componentName) {
        if( !componentName ) {
            return;
        }
        var option = component.find(componentName);
        if($A.util.hasClass(option, "slds-is-selected")) {
            $A.util.removeClass(option, "slds-is-selected");
        } else {
            $A.util.addClass(option, "slds-is-selected");
        }
    },

    setInputBar : function(component, content) {
        var selectedText = component.find(content).getElement().textContent;
        var selectedBox = component.find("selectedOption").getElement();
        selectedBox.value = selectedText;
    }, 

    storeAsCurrentlyCheckedValue : function(component, currentOptionId, currentOptionIconId, currentPaddingId) {
        var currentIdStorage = [currentOptionId, currentOptionIconId, currentPaddingId];
        component.set("v.currentCheckedPicklistIds", currentIdStorage);
    },

    resetPreviousCheckedOption : function(component) {
        var optionIds = component.get("v.currentCheckedPicklistIds");
        this.checkOption(component, optionIds[0]);
        this.showOptionIcon(component, optionIds[1], optionIds[2]);
    }
})
```

A screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

The reason I had to add all that Javascript was because the SLDS documentation does not show how to transition between states. The Javascript supplements that.

Note: at the moment, once you click an option, you cannot leave the picklist blank, that is, it won't go back to the initial state. My solution may not be the most scalable... You can divide, if it's possible, each of the options in the picklist to be a separate component, and create events to callout to the `<aura:attribute>`.